# android google maps v2 want to show 2 Market show

Tags: android, google-maps

I  have tryied Like [with 2 Lat Long Details]

```
              final LatLng latlong = new LatLng(lat,lng);
              final LatLng latlongcr = new LatLng(currentlat,currentlong);

                 mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlongcr).title("Here You Are"));
                 mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).title(addr));

                 mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 20));
                 mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlongcr, 20));
                 mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20), 2000, null);
```

But Get Only One Marker. want to show 2 marker Mapview working fine

Comment: your code is correct.. just take reference from here https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-/blob/master/getDirectionGoogleMap/src/com/DJAndroid/getDirection/showMaps.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `LatLngBounds.Builder`:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(latlongcr);
builder.include(latlong);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
mapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));
```